# Java nio server always stuck on selector.select

Tags: java, nio

I'm trying to write a simple client server model using NIO (to learn how it works). There are 2 types of messages that can be sent Connection (which is a message the server sends to a client when it connects giving it info like its client id) and Ping.

If a client has not been pinged for a time period of > 4 seconds the server will ping the client and the client will respond with a pong.

When I initialize my server I do it like so:

```
    try{
        selector = Selector.open();
        selector.wakeup();
        serverChannel = selector.provider().openServerSocketChannel();
        serverChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
        serverChannel.configureBlocking(false);

        serverChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
    }catch (IOException e){
        log.Error(e);
        throw new RuntimeException("Error opening selector.", e);
    }
```

after this happens we enter our server loop which will find what keys have been selected and performed the selected operation on the keys

```
int select = 0;

    while (running){ 
        try{
           select = selector.select(timeout);

           if(select == 0){
               continue;
           }
           Iterator<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();

           while(selectedKeys.hasNext()){
               SelectionKey key = selectedKeys.next();
               selectedKeys.remove();

               Connection conn = (Connection)key.attachment();

               if(conn != null){
                   if(key.isValid() && key.isReadable()){
                                  //handle key reads
                   }
                   if(key.isValid() && key.isWritable()){
                          //handle key writes
                   }

                   continue;
               }

               if(key.isValid() && key.isAcceptable()){
                   Connection newConn = new Connection(transport, packetFactory, nextConnectionId);

                   try{
                       SelectionKey selectionKey = newConn.getConnection().handleAccept(selector, serverChannel.accept());
                       selectionKey.attach(newConn);

                            //send the client a connection message

                       nextConnectionId++;
                   }catch(IOException e){
                       newConn.close();
                       log.Error(e);
                   }
               }
           }

           long time = System.nanoTime();
           for(Connection c : connections){
               if(c.getConnection().isTimedOut(time)){
                   c.close();
                }

                if(c.needsPing(time)) {
                    c.sendPing();
                }
           }
        }catch(IOException e){
            log.Error(e);
        }
    }
```

the handleAccept() method looks like so

```
public SelectionKey handleAccept(Selector selector, SocketChannel ch) {

    try{
        socketChannel = ch;
        socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        lastReadTime = System.nanoTime();
        selectionKey = ch.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);

        return selectionKey;
    }catch(IOException e){
        close();
    }
}
```

the handleAccept() method is part of the connection object which holds information such as the connections socketChannel, selectionkey. Whenever the connection is read/write these are updated like so:

```
public void handleWrite(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
    socketChannel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
    this.selectionKey = key;

    //do other stuff
 }
```

finally when we need to write something to the client we tell the socketChannel that we're interested in writing and once we finish writing we tell it we want to read. This is done by accessing the connections selection key and setting its `interestOps()` to the correct field.

When I run this code the server does the following:

```
[2014/05/25 01:49:23] [INFO] [com.adammflax.net.ServerEndPoint] Started Server on port 9001
[2014/05/25 01:49:26] [INFO] [com.adammflax.net.ServerEndPoint] Added the connection com.adammflax.net.Connection@4838ddcc to the list of connections on the server
[2014/05/25 01:49:26] [INFO] [com.adammflax.net.ServerEndPoint] Client com.adammflax.net.Connection@4838ddcc connected to the server given a Id of 0
30
[CLIENT RECEIVES CONNECTION PACKET]
[2014/05/25 01:49:26] [DEBUG] [com.adammflax.net.ServerEndPoint] Received ping from client now replying
[CLIENT RECEIVES Ping PACKET]
```

after this however the server just gets stuck on selector.select() (it will always timeout and return 0). Can anyone explain to me why this is happening. I know this is a lot of code to dig through (and bits are missing to try and condense this) but any help on the matter would be amazing.

edit
adding more code to show how we detect if a ping needs to happen (which belongs to the connection object)

```
public boolean needsPing(long time) {
    if(!isConnected()){
        return false;
    }

    if(pingTime <= 0){
        return false;
    }

    if(time <= lastPingSentTime + pingTime){
        return false;
    }

    lastPingSentTime = System.nanoTime();

    return true;
}
```

send ping  turns  a pingPacket object into bytes and calls the send Method which adds the bytes to a messageQueue called messages.

```
public void send(byte[] message) {
    messages.add(message);
    selectionKey.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
}
```

as we are now in OP_WRITE `handleWrite` will eventually be called

```
public void handleWrite(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
    socketChannel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();

    if(socketChannel == null){
        key.cancel();
        throw new SocketException("Socket connection has closed!");
    }

    while(!messages.isEmpty()){
        try{
            writeBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(messages.peek());


            if(socketChannel.write(writeBuffer) == 0){
                break;
            }

            if (writeBuffer.remaining() > 0) {
                break;
            }

            writeBuffer.compact();
            messages.poll(); //everything went well so remove head
        }catch(IOException e){
            log.Error("failed to write : " + messages.peek() + " at " +
                    this.socketChannel.getRemoteAddress());
        }
    }   

    selectionKey.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
}
```

Comment: "When we need to write something to the client we tell the socketChannel that we're interested in writing." That's not how you do it. Just write when you need to, and if you get a short write count *then* register OP_WRITE etc, and unregister it when you complete the write. At present you're just adding pointless latency.

Comment: sorry EJP I should of explained better currently if we want to send something we add it to a message queue, when something gets added to the message queue OP_WRITE gets registered. Then on the next iteration handleWrite will be called which will then loop through all items in the message queue, send them to the client and then OP_READ will get registered. BY doing it this way we can make sure we are not blocking until we're in a position to send the data

Comment: It's still the wrong way to do it. You're in non-blocking mode. Ergo you can't block. I don't understand what you're expecting to happen after the trace you provided. There's no evidence that any further network activity is taking place, so why are you expecting select() to return non-zero?

Comment: (I'll change how the write is done) as for the part of the comment as ping is set to be sent every 4 seconds eventually select should return a value > 0 as we need to send the PING to the client. However this doesn't happen instead it hangs.

Comment: Where is the code that causes that to happen? Do you have any evidence that it actually works? Also why are you calling wakeup() as soon as you've created the Selector? It's pointless.

Comment: at the bottom of the code in the while(running) loop, if we've looped over all the keys we then loop over every connection and send a ping to anything that needs a ping.

Comment: Don't tell me. Show me. Where is needsPing()? Where is sendPing()? You're asking questions about code you haven't posted. This is also pointless.

Comment: I cut them out as it was taking a lot of room I'll post them up now (also should this prehaps be moved to a chat?)